# не выводит ошибку если поле не заполнено (PHP)

Tags: php

`

```html
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>forma</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="test"action="check.php"method="post">
    <label>Nume*</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="name"placeholder="Nume*"/>
    <label>Email*</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    <form name="test"action="check.php"method="post">
    <label>Subiect*</label><br/>
    <form name="text"action="check.php"method="post">
    <label>Mesaj</label><br/>
    <textarea name="message"cols="40" rows="30"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit"name="done" value="Trimite email"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

`Подскажите, пожалуйста в чем проблема не выводит ошибку если поле не заполнено (PHP)`                `.<?php

if ($_POST["name"] == "" )

echo "Вы не ввели имя.";

Comment: if (!isset($_POST["name"]))

Comment: не работает выводится так :Array ( [name] => [email] => [message] => [done] => Trimite email )

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>forma</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="test"action="check.php"method="post">
<label>Nume*</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="name"placeholder="Nume*"/>
<label>Email*</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
<form name="test"action="check.php"method="post">
<label>Subiect*</label><br/>
<form name="text"action="check.php"method="post">

Comment: <label>Mesaj</label><br/>
<textarea name="message"cols="40" rows="30"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit"name="done" value="Trimite email"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php



if (!isset($_POST["name"]))

echo "Вы не ввели имя.";

Answer (score 0):

if (isset($_POST["name"]) and $_POST["name"] == "" )

echo "Вы не ввели имя.";

Первая проверка на наличие запроса , далее уже верификация на пустоту + чего надо еще.

Answer (score -2):

```html
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>forma</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="test"action="check.php"method="post">
    <label>Nume*</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="name"placeholder="Nume*"/>
    <label>Email*</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    <form name="test"action="check.php"method="post">
    <label>Subiect*</label><br/>
    <form name="text"action="check.php"method="post">
    <label>Mesaj</label><br/>
    <textarea name="message"cols="40" rows="30"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit"name="done" value="Trimite email"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <?php



    if (empty($_Get["name"]))

    echo "Voi nu a introdus nume.";


    if (!isset($_Get["email"]))

    echo "Voi nu a inrodus email.";



     
    ?>
```